# Track python warnings in VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I want to know what line of code causes warning raising in my code. Is it possible to do it in VScode? For example, I see warning in terminal:
[image]

As for now, I can see only the imported module that raises a warning in python terminal, but I can't track it to the exact line of my code, only to the line of an imported module. Probably, it's possible to add a breakpoint on warnings or to change some settings, or to use an extension?

Comment: give an example of what you see and want

Comment: @DmytroSytro -In VSCode, the function of debugging Python is provided by the Python extension. The code will stop at the problematic code position during debugging. In addition, we can also check the position of the error or warning through the "_PROBLEMS_" panel, for example: "unresolved import ' pandas' Python(unresolved-import) [2,8]"

Comment: The warnings can arise not from the import itself, but from the usage of those imported packages. That's why those warnings aren't shown in "PROBLEMS"

Comment: @DmytroSytro -Could you please provide us with a code snippet that minimizes the reproduction of this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Have you added the standard python extension for vs code?
This should normally display warnings in your code.

You can go to Preferences => Extensions and then search for 'Python' to download extensions for python.

Comment: Yep, I have standard python exention.